# Establish Concurrent Websocket Connections to server Using Python Twisted Websocket Client

Tags: python, websocket, concurrency, connection, twisted

I'm trying to open concurrent websocket connections from client end(which has 60k ports limit per machine) using Python Twisted Authobhan Websocket Client.But I'm unable to open not more than 20k connections using below code:

```
from autobahn.twisted.websocket import WebSocketClientProtocol, WebSocketClientFactory

class WebSocketClient(WebSocketClientProtocol):

    def _handshake_request(self):
        pass

    def onOpen(self):
        self._handshake_request()

    def onConnect(self, response):
        pass
    def onMessage(self,data):
        pass


class WebSocketFactory(WebSocketClientFactory):

    """WebSocketClient Factory"""

    protocol = WebSocketClient

if __name__ == '__main__':

    factory = WebSocketFactory()

    ##### Note here. ######
    for _ in range(num_connections):
        reactor.connectTCP(ws_url, ws_port, factory)
    #####

    reactor.run()
```

I have used "reactor.connectTCP" in a loop, Does it the correct way to open the concurrent websocket connections using Twisted?

Let me know.

Answer (score 0):

You need to perform fewer *concurrent* connection attempts.  You may be able to sustain 20k or more connections but you won't be able to establish them all simultaneously.

Limit yourself to a few dozen or a hundred at a time.  You may want to use `twisted.internet.task.cooperate` for this.

Comment: Why limit to few dozens connections?? It's a client side webSocket application which try to make 60k connections to the server.But, due to  reactor loop CPU one core shoots up to 100% and other cores aren't used.I have connectTCP in a loop for opening multiple connections to the server.Am I doing something wrong?Or should approach in some other way? can't we make connections using multiprocessing in Twisted so that all cores could be utilized for making connections?

Comment: *connection attempts*.  Not *connections*.  Put another way, don't try to *start* 60k connections at once.  Try to *start* a few dozen or a hundred at once (exactly how many depends on your network resources).  Once the connections are *established* you can maintain them while you *start* more.